# How to manage data passing?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am currently working on Module 1 of my app & setting design for it which I want to apply for other Modules too.

I have below elements in Module 1

1. MainActivity -> 3 Fragments [A, B, C]
2. All 3 Fragments contain -> ViewPager
3. Each ViewPager has -> 5 Fragments [p, q, r, s, t]
4. All of ViewPager fragments are kind of input forms & want to share data from ViewPager's Fragment 1 to 2 to 3 till 5. On Fragment 5, SAVE button enable which saves data. (assume fragment 1-5 means p-t)
5. Another part is Fragment 1 or A is like container which has code of ViewPager to load 5 sub fragments & get data from sequential fragments & pass further.

My Question is,

**This seems very much & want to Is it the correct way to do this or Should I change this design pattern? And, if this design approach is correct then How should I manage data passing?**

Comment: What's different between the 3 main fragments? are they just updating different objects? Where do you display the final updated data? or do you just store it and continue to show the input forms? Also, item 5 is not very clear. Does fragment A has a special case different from the scenario described in 1-4?

Comment: Will answer Q by Q. 3 Fragments are 3 different sub flows. All are independent but can get data using SQLIte which is saved from earlier fragment. Just collecting data & sending to API & SQLite. Fragment is having few input fields along with SAVE button & 1-4 having only SWIPE feature to move next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that you'll have different ways to do it, and none is the correct only easier or cleaner to do.
So, if i were you, i would try to separate the domain objects, and have a model for the Data and the views only handling the view part.
The best, for me, is to follow the MVVM pattern which gives you lot of control, and you can read about it on Google android databinding library docs.

Another way is hacking it, lets say, have a Singleton WorkFlowManager that all Views can access, and have all the data and Business Logic in it.
This way the Any Fragment/Activity can check if all the form fields are set and make the Save button visible (for instance).
If you want to update the views with events you can create custom eventListeners on the Manager and as soon as the last field is filled trigger that a FormFilledEvent (or similar) and have the Fragment register that event to listen for it, and make the Buttton visible .

This is one Use case, but you can have multiple

Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

> This seems very much & want to Is it the correct way to do this or
>   Should I change this design pattern

It does seem a little too complex design to me. I would rather keep all the 5 fragments of the `ViewPager` as one form with a save FAB/button to avoid passing the data from the main fragment to each of the sub-fragments. However, that may result in a very long form in the case you are describing, or too many checks if fields depend on previous ones.

> if this design approach is correct then How should I manage data
>   passing?

For each main `Fragment`, I would use one object that implements [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) for the whole sub-flow that gets loaded from the database on the main fragment, then passed to sub-fragments one at a time filling corresponding fields. The last sub-fragment would be responsible for saving the updated object to the database, or just pass it back to the main fragment for saving

## **Update:**

I haven't tested this code, but here is one way how I would pass the data from the main fragment to sub-fragments:

**MainFragment.java**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment 
{    
    private MyObj myObj;
    private SubFragment currentFragment;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, parent, false);
        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        myObj = db.loadObject();
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        return view;
    }

    public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {

        MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
        {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            if(currentFragment != null) myObj = currentFragment.getMyObj();
            switch(position)
            {
               case 4: 
                   currentFragment = FragmentT.getInstance(myObj);
                   break;
               case 3: 
                   currentFragment =  FragmentS.getInstance(myObj);
                   break;
               case 2: 
                   currentFragment =  FragmentR.getInstance(myObj);
                   break;
               case 1: 
                   currentFragment = FragmentQ.getInstance(myObj);
                   break;
               case 0: 
               default: 
                   currentFragment = FragmentP.getInstance(myObj);
            }
            return currentFragmnet;
         }

         @Override
         public int getCount()
         {
            return 5;
         }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
        {
            return titles[position]; 
        }
    }
}
```

**SubFragment.java**

```
public class SubFragment extends Fragment
{
    protected static final String ARGS = "args";

    protected MyObj myObj;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null)
        {
            myObj = args.getParcelable(ARGS);
        }
    }

    public MyObj getMyObj()
    {
        return myObj;
    }
}
```

**FragmentP.java**

```
public class FragmentP extends SubFragment
{        
    public static FragmentP getInstance(MyObj myObj)
    {
        final FragmentP fragment = new FragmentP();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable(ARGS, myObj);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: No but how you will manage to pass data on SWIPE from fragment 1 to another. I mean how will you manage page change listener inside sub fragments.

Comment: @VVB I have updated my answer with some code of one way I would pass data to subfragments

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using Observer design pattern. Make your models observable and register all ui components to be update as observers. I would recommend RXjava to solve this.